# How to replace "Unknowns" in R

Tags: r

```
id        Date created  gender     age
5uwns89zht  7/1/2014    FEMALE     35
jtl0dijy2j  7/1/2014    -unknown-   -
xx0ulgorjt  7/1/2014    -unknown-   -
6c6puo6ix0  7/1/2014    -unknown-   -
czqhjk3yfe  7/1/2014    -unknown-   -
```

Hi,

I wanted to understand how do we replace the missing values in the gender column with *NULL* or *NA* and how do we fill in the missing values in age?

I tried the replacement function for Unknowns as follows:

```
traindata_z$gender<-replace('-unknown-', np.nan, inplace = TRUE)
```

And for missing values, I am not sure what code do I pass.

Could you help me with this please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
traindata_z$gender<- gsub("-unknown-",NA,traindata_z$gender)
traindata_z$age<- gsub("-",NA,traindata_z$age)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following options.

```
# option 1
traindata_z$gender[traindata_z$gender == "-unknown-"] <- NA
# option 2
traindata_z$gender <- ifelse(traindata_z$gender == "-unknown-",
                             NA, traindata_z$gender)
```